# Disable orientation change - WindowManager

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-windowmanager

I am developing a Lock Screen application in which i am adding a View using WindowManager in a Service. 
I have set Orientation PORTRAIT in manifest file for all activities but that doesn't seem to work for this dynamically added view.

Please see below code snippet

```
    public class LockerService extends Service{
        @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
                windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                lockScreenView = new LockScreenView(this, this);
                windowManager.addView(lockScreenView, params);
    }
}
```

Lockscreen view as follows:

```
public class LockScreenView extends RelativeLayout{
public LockScreenView(Context context, ScreenUnlockedDeligate screenUnlockedDeligate) {
        super(context);
         setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_lock, this);

    }

}
```

Is there any way i could disable orientation change for this view? i.e `Orientation.PORTRAIT`

**EDIT:**

> > setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
>
> doesn't seems to be available in this context

Thanks in advance!!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, i found a solution.

Adding

> params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

before adding the view will solve the issue and lock the orientation as desired.

like:

```
    public class LockerService extends Service{
            @Override
                public void onCreate() {
                    super.onCreate();
                    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                    lockScreenView = new LockScreenView(this, this);
                    params.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                    windowManager.addView(lockScreenView, params);
        }
    }
```